# How to test react navigation authentication flow?

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I'm developing a React Native application. I'm doing something like what's explained [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/auth-flow/) to implement the authentication flow. So, I created an `AppContainer` that looks like this:

```js
import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation";
import AuthLoadingScreen from "../screens/auth/auth-loading-screen";

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: {screen: HomeScreen} });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: {screen: SignInScreen} });

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "AuthLoading",
    },
  ),
);

export {AppContainer};
export default AppContainer;
```

Then, here's what I have in my `App.tsx`:

```js
import React from "react";
import AppContainer from "./src/navigation/index";

const App = () => {
  return <AppContainer />;
};

export default App;
```

And, here is my `App.test.tsx`:

```js
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

Here's the `jest` configuration in my `package.json` file:

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|@react-native-community/*|react-navigation|react-navigation-stack|@react-navigation/.*)"
    ],
    "timers": "fake",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  },
```

Now, when I run `yarn test`, the test passes, but I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at Object.get useTheme [as useTheme] (node_modules/@react-navigation/core/lib/commonjs/index.js:3:18)
      at Object.get [as useTheme] (node_modules/react-navigation/src/index.js:169:19)
      at useTheme (node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/commonjs/utils/useTheme.js:65:36)
      at CardContainer (node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/commonjs/vendor/views/Stack/CardContainer.tsx:165:5)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5762:18) PASS  __tests__/App-test.tsx (10.657s)   ✓ renders correctly (93ms)

  console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10695
    The above error occurred in the <CardContainer> component:
        in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
        in View (created by View)
        in View (created by MaybeScreen)
        in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
        in View (created by View)
        in View (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
        in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
        in CardStack (created by KeyboardManager)
        in KeyboardManager (created by Context.Consumer)
        in RNCSafeAreaView (created by RNCSafeAreaView)
        in RNCSafeAreaView (at src/index.tsx:28)
        in SafeAreaProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
        in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
        in View (created by View)
        in View (created by StackView)
        in StackView (created by StackView)
        in StackView
        in Unknown (created by Navigator)
        in Navigator (created by SceneView)
        in SceneView (created by SwitchView)
        in SwitchView (created by Navigator)
        in Navigator (created by NavigationContainer)
        in NavigationContainer (created by App)
        in App

    React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, NavigationContainer.

  console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10695
    The above error occurred in the <NavigationContainer> component:
        in NavigationContainer (created by App)
        in App

    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had some async functions in my authentication flow. So, all I had to do was to change the test method to an async one, like below:

```js
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', async () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some config for your jest:

1) create a folder in your root directory `__mocks__` and then file insid that with name: `react-navigation.js` and put this below code inside that:

```
export default {
   NavigationActions: () => {}
};
```

2) create a file in your root with this name: `jest.config.js` and put these codes inside:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'react-native',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
      './__mocks__/mockFirebase'
    ],
    automock: false,
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
      "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Also, you can add your other config to this file, and after that remove `jest config` from your `package.json` file

3) Also probably you need to add some other files to `__mocks__` folder:

`react-native-gesture-handler.js` file with below codes:

```
export const RectButton = () => 'View';
export const State = () => 'View';
export const LongPressGestureHandler = () => 'View';
export const BorderlessButton = () => 'View';
export const PanGestureHandler = () => 'View';
```

and for some other packages similar: `react-native-device-info`, `Firebase`, `@react-native-community` you need do similar things, you can ask here or search 
 about that on Google.

Comment: Thank you! `./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js` in the `setupFiles` of my jest configuration takes care of mocking `react-native-gesture-handler`. I already resolved the issue. There's no need to mock `react-navigation`, at least so far with what I'm testing. I just had to change the snapshot test to an async one, because I do have async functions in my authentication flow.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jest fake timers to turn it async

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
```

So your code will look like this:

```
import App from '../src';
jest.useFakeTimers();

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```